# Unable to access Alamofire file

Tags: swift3

I am using Xcode8.1GM & AFNetworking 4.0.
I have add AFNetworking file using Pods and trying to access Alamofire Class.
but i'm unable to access this class.
What should i do?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the framework in the swift file before you use it. Add

```
import Alamofire
```

below `import UIKit`

After that try to run the project once it should compile successfully and then you are good to go.

Comment: It will show but run it once and check if it builds successful?